# programatically selected values are not highlighted in select2 (4.1.0)

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2, jquery-select2-4

I wanted to open the dropdown problematically then select values
Corrugated Cardboard & Smooth cardboard are problematically selected but not highlighted

```
$('#materials').select2({
  allowClear: true,
  width: '100%',
  data: materials,
  closeOnSelect: false,
});
$('#materials').select2('open');

$('#materials').val([14,15]).trigger("change");
```

[image]

but it gets highlighted after manually selecting another items
[image]

Comment: Try putting `$('#materials').val([14,15]).trigger("change");` line before opening your select2 .

Comment: it works like that , but the dropdown has to be opened first ,I have some buttons if the buttons are clicked then different values will be changed